# What do these lines in a Makefile mean?

Tags: bash, makefile

I am having to quickly grok a Makefile, to understand some issues I'm having. I have come across these lines, and I want to make sure I'm understanding their use here correctly.

```
cp $< $@
sed -i -e 's#{{DEPLOY}}#https://example.com/#g' $@
```

To be clear, I know that `sed` is being used to make a (global?) string substitution here, but the use of bash special characters make this perhaps more confusing than it should be.

Would appreciate explanation on what the two lines above are actually doing.

Comment: I would recommend replacing the `copy and inplace sed` logic with sed to the output, i.e. `sed  -e 's#{{DEPLOY}}#https://example.com/#g' $< > $@`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [GNU Make automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

> `$@`
>   The file name of the target of the rule. If the target is an archive member, then ‘$@’ is the name of the archive file. In a pattern rule that has multiple targets (see Introduction to Pattern Rules), ‘$@’ is the name of whichever target caused the rule’s recipe to be run.
>
> `$<` The name of the first prerequisite. If the target got its recipe from an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by the implicit rule (see Implicit Rules).

See [what targets and prerequisites are](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction).

---

```
sed -i -e 's#{{DEPLOY}}#https://example.com/#g' $@
```

Replaces all occurrences of `{{DEPLOY}}` with `https://example.com/` in `$@`.

---

Putting all together, a simpler and more robust version of

```
cp $< $@
sed -i -e 's#{{DEPLOY}}#https://example.com/#g' $@
```

is:

```
sed -e 's#{{DEPLOY}}#https://example.com/#g' $< > $@
```

Comment: To be clear, these are not Bash special characters, but Make special characters.

Comment: What does `file name of the target of the rule` and `The name of the first prerequisite` mean in **simple English**? Also, what is the `sed` command *ACTUALLY* doing?

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Added more words for you.